# How can i get the project name in Big Query that I'm working on?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I need to get the project name that i'm actually working on Big Query in a field within the tables inside of the project.

This is the query I'm working at the moment:

```
SELECT A.table_name FROM `myproject.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` A where A.table_name in ('tbl_project1','tbl_project2','tbl_project3');
```

But i also need to retrieve the project name in that view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#tables_view), you can obtain the ID of the project that contains the dataset including the `table_catalog` column in your query:

```sql
SELECT A.table_catalog, A.table_name FROM `myproject.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` A where A.table_name in ('tbl_project1','tbl_project2','tbl_project3');
```

Comment: It worked, thank you for the documentation and the example :D

Comment: You are welcome @EduardoOrtiz. I am glad to help.